# How to make change on the video stream in real time ?

Tags: android

I want to make some change on the video that come from the camera. 
So i using class that extends the class SurfaceView  and implements SurfaceHolder.Callback.

Now, i still don't find any way to make this change. 
How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is complicated and difficult to do in realtime.  Basically you need to grab the camera data, modify it, then write it to the SurfaceView.  And you realistically have half a second to do it, otherwise the lag is unbearable.

Apps that overlay things on a camera view (think of the ZXing barcode scanner) typically do it by providing a view bound to the camera, then grabbing a second copy of the camera image data a few times per second and overlaying additional data on top of the first view.

Answer (score 3):

you can try SurfaceTexture instead of SurfaceView, and implements interface SurfaceTexture.OnFrameAvailableListener with method onFrameAvailable(...).  On arrival of video frame, Surface will call back this method, you can get the current frame data.

Pls refer to class PanoramaActivity of Android Camera APK source code for sampling code.